# How can I optimize this query further?

Tags: mysql

This is mysql query to which I have added the indexes wherever possible. This is written by some previous coders and I need to optimize it as coming in slow logs. I have following stats for this query:

```
     rows_sent: 1
    query_time: 00:10:31
     lock_time: 00:00:00
 rows_examined: 628241089
            db: singledb_ed
last_insert_id: 0
     insert_id: 0
     server_id: 1789791470
      sql_text: SELECT cs.delivery_consultant_id AS user_id, 
interview.id AS interview_id,
date(interview.interview_date) AS interview_date, 
date(interview.mod_date) AS interview_mod_date,
count(interview.id) AS kpi_item_count,
cu.division_id,
bu.organisation_id,
ctu.team_id
 FROM es_shortlist AS cs
 LEFT JOIN tms_vacancies AS vac ON cs.vacancy_id = vac.id
 LEFT JOIN es_applications AS app ON app.vacancy_id = vac.id AND app.candidate_id = cs.candidate_id
 LEFT JOIN tms_interviews AS interview ON app.id = interview.application_id
 LEFT JOIN company_users AS cu ON cu.id = cs.delivery_consultant_id
 LEFT JOIN base_users AS bu ON bu.company_user_id = cs.delivery_consultant_id AND bu.company_id = cu.base_company_id
 LEFT JOIN company_team_users AS ctu ON ctu.user_id = cs.delivery_consultant_id
WHERE (ctu.end_date is null
  AND cs.delivery_consultant_id ='53521')
  AND (ctu.end_date IS NULL)
  AND (ctu.status = 2)
GROUP BY cs.delivery_consultant_id, ctu.team_id
```

EXPLAIN RESULT:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys                                             | key                    | key_len | ref                                   | rows | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cs        | ref    | delivery_consultant_id                                    | delivery_consultant_id | 5       | const                                 | 1421 | Using temporary; Using filesort    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vac       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                   | PRIMARY                | 4       | singledb_ed.cs.vacancy_id             |    1 | Using index                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | app       | ref    | vacancy_id,candidate_stage_sync                           | vacancy_id             | 5       | singledb_ed.vac.id                    |    1 | Using where                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | interview | ref    | application_id                                            | application_id         | 4       | singledb_ed.app.id                    |    1 | NULL                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cu        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                   | PRIMARY                | 4       | singledb_ed.cs.delivery_consultant_id |    1 | NULL                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bu        | ref    | company_user_id,company_id,getOrganisation,get_index_comp | company_user_id        | 5       | singledb_ed.cs.delivery_consultant_id |    1 | Using where                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ctu       | ref    | user_id,status,end_date                                   | end_date               | 6       | const                                 |   40 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
```

[Please see this image for EXPLAIN result of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J30y6.jpg)

The CREATE INFO for all Tables

```html
CREATE TABLE `es_shortlist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vacancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `candidate_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shortlist_status` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 = open / 0 = closed / 2 = inprocess',
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `entity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivery_consultant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_cb_migrated` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rs_app_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shortlist_source` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=''System'', 2=''Web Response''',
  `shortlist_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '24=''job board'', 43=''indeed'', 44=''google'', ''other is direct''',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `delivery_consultant_id` (`delivery_consultant_id`),
  KEY `candidate_id` (`candidate_id`),
  KEY `vacancy_id` (`vacancy_id`),
  KEY `created_user_id` (`created_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39388 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `tms_vacancies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `base_company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `organisation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ref for vacancy_id',
  `eb_reff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'attach id of tms_teams table',
  `function_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `division_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qualified` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lead_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - was not a lead,1 - was a lead initially',
  `lead_category` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If in lead_type field value set as 1 then must be set 5 = Market Info, 6 = Hot Lead, 7 = Job Ad',
  `source` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1-contract, 2-permanent and 3-part time etc\n',
  `reason` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reason for vacancy, try to get that info at the time of creating lead\n\nEg.\nNew Role / \r\n\r\nReplacement - Resignation / Maternity / Sickness / Replacement - Internal Transfer / Replacement - Dismissed',
  `job_title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'look up - ACCOUNTS OBJECT (NOTICE. An account have to be created before adding a LEAD)',
  `start_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_salary` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'This field is used to store min value of base salary for permanent type of job',
  `base_salary_upto` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'This field is used to store max value of base salary for permanent type of job',
  `base_salary_to` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'This field is used to store min value of total package for permanent type of job',
  `base_salary_to_upto` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'This field is used to store max value of total package for permanent type of job',
  `salary_in_base_currency` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Salary converted into base currecy',
  `package_in_base_currency` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Total Package converted into base currecy',
  `application_form_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'This Field will show if a vacancy has application created against it or not',
  `application_auto_reject_flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_reject_score` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch_office` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `approval_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0=>Unapproved, 1=>Approved',
  `role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rs_sc_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rs_sc_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rs_sc_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endorsed_vacancy` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `percentage_agreed` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee_agreed` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee_agreed_in_base_currency` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Fee converted into base currecy',
  `excange_rate` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'curreny exchange rate for current month',
  `fee_calculation_from` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_fee` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag_qualified` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc_background_cover` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bonus` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `benefits` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `no_required` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'how many positions are to fill',
  `placement_nos` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'no of placement done against vacancy_id',
  `summary` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `jobpost_summary` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1-poen, 2-closed, 3-placed',
  `priority` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_reason` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `3ff_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `contract_length` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `function` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expenses` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `working_commitment` int(11) DEFAULT '100',
  `base_rate_to` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `daily_client_rate` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'calculate if rate is hourly we save client rate * 8 otherwise as it is client rate',
  `daily_candidate_rate` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'calculate if rate is hourly we save candidate rate * 8 otherwise as it is candidate rate',
  `client_rate_in_base_curreny` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Client rate converted into base currecy',
  `candidate_rate_in_base_currency` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Candidate rate converted into base currecy',
  `candidate_base_rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exp_included` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_rate_currency` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `client_job_description` text,
  `interview_template_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_template_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_mod_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mod_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `closed_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag_post_jobboard` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_post_supplier` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_post_tpool` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_post_social` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_post_referral` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_relocate` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=> job will allow candidate that are not wiiling to relocate ,1=> job will allow candidate that are willing to relocate',
  `rs_summary` text,
  `created_a_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_b_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_lead_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_teaser` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_pitched` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_block` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `job_role_id` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'combination of jobrole_id and category_id(like 8117##8), ## is seperator',
  `search_by` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 : All of the Skill, 2: Any of the skill',
  `is_removed` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_third_rep` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_cb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_eb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_posting_approved` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_posted` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `merge_account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rs_vacancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `migrated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_onhold_closeplaced` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=Not, 1=Close Application of on hold & closed placed jobs more than 30 days old',
  `cron_first_grade_a_job_dm` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `cron_first_grade_a_job_acc` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `fee_agreed_gbp` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee_agreed_usd` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee_agreed_eur` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee_cron_updated` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `org_id_updated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `teamid_updated` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_digital` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=>deactive,1=>active',
  `is_new` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1-New Job',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `base_company_id` (`base_company_id`),
  KEY `tms_vacancy_idx` (`function_id`,`status`,`flag_post_jobboard`,`flag_post_supplier`,`flag_post_tpool`),
  KEY `organisation_id` (`organisation_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `created_date` (`created_date`),
  KEY `job_close` (`organisation_id`,`status`,`created_date`),
  KEY `is_new` (`is_new`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80611 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Tabe for storing lead details by recruiters.\n\nA lead is a co';

CREATE TABLE `es_applications` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `candidate_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dm_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_status` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active_batch` tinyint(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 if current batch, 0 if batch deactive',
  `rejection_stage` tinyint(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `rejection_status` tinyint(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'reason for rejection',
  `rejection_status_reason` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COMMENT 'comments for rejection',
  `rejection_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_user_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'dm/HR or Line Manager',
  `from_user_type` tinyint(5) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'dm/HR or Line Manager',
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sharedby_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sharedby_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `mod_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mod_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `current_sub_status` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `app_stage` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'application stage',
  `enterprise_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enterprise_user_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cv_send_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edmgr_vacancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vacancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_branch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Branch id of job',
  `talent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_status` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stage_reached` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stage_reached_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary` text CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `is_available` tinyint(5) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 for available and 0 for not available',
  `candidate_type` tinyint(5) DEFAULT '2' COMMENT '2=permanent, 3= contract',
  `send_list_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Primary id of es_endorsed_send_list table ',
  `is_direct` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - not direct, 1 - direct application',
  `is_hot` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 - Hot, 0 - Not Hot',
  `organisation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `candidate_source` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `candidate_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rs_app_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_teaser` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `branch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `merge_account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entity_org_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `team_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orgid_teamid_updated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `application_type` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `es_talent_profile` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_sourcechain_account` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_cron` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_cb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_eb_migrated` tinyint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_tr_cron` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dm_id` (`dm_id`),
  KEY `current_status` (`current_status`,`cv_send_id`,`vacancy_id`),
  KEY `vacancy_id` (`vacancy_id`),
  KEY `candidate_stage_sync` (`candidate_id`,`app_status`,`current_sub_status`),
  KEY `start_date` (`base_company_id`,`dm_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `start_date_2` (`start_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=112073 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tms_interviews` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `base_company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stage` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'whether it is 1st or 2nd or 3rd or final.',
  `sub_stage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'it will hold total count of interview for same application',
  `ref_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ref for interviewer_id',
  `interviewer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `interview_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'interview date .',
  `interview_time` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'interview time .',
  `interview_type` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1=>FTF, 2=>telephonic',
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'could be accepted or rejected.',
  `status_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_reason` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'the reason why candidate is rejected at this stage.',
  `application_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `candidate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vacancy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_table` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `client_feedback` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `candidate_feedback` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `cp_feedback` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `note` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mod_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_mod_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reff_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `performance_cron_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_zone` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmation_flag` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `interview_where` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'used for where field in interview scheduling',
  `location` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_cancelled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `no_of_reschedules` int(3) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'No of reschedules',
  `merge_account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_cron` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_cb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_eb_migrated` tinyint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tms_interviews_idx` (`stage`,`interviewer_id`,`status`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `application_id` (`application_id`),
  KEY `candidate_id` (`candidate_id`),
  KEY `vacancy_id` (`vacancy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=60447 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='store interview stages for candidates for particular applica';

CREATE TABLE `company_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dpn_sent` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Pending(1) | Sent(2) | Bounced(3) | Verified(4)',
  `email_verification_status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1:Good, 2: Bad',
  `dpn_due_date` datetime DEFAULT '2018-06-24 00:00:00',
  `base_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_portal_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'client portal id if user is of client portal',
  `crm_people_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'client user id-people_id',
  `education_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `division_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` int(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'no constraint should be made on this',
  `picture` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `function_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_module_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'verified, activated, deactivated, approved',
  `endorsed_user` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `endorsed_dm_status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_mod_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mod_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_onboarding_message` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=>not onboarding,1=>onboarded',
  `is_onboarding_connection` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=>not onboarding,1=>onboarded',
  `is_onboarding_profile` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=>not onboarding,1=>onboarded',
  `hub_integrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0:NotIntegrated, 1:Integrated',
  `hub_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cloud_integrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `cloud_contact_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cloud_integrated_eb` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `cloud_contact_id_eb` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cloud_integrated_tr` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `cloud_contact_id_tr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_cb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_eb_migrated` tinyint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `eb_reff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_marketing_org_sync` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '2',
  `field_hub_sync` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0:No;1:Yes',
  `is_jt_synced` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0:no;1:yes',
  `cloud_integrated_vado` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `cloud_contact_id_vado` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `merge_account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_dm_emp_hub_sync` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_missing_name` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`,`client_portal_id`),
  KEY `mod_date` (`mod_date`),
  KEY `base_company_id` (`base_company_id`),
  KEY `created_user_id` (`created_user_id`),
  KEY `last_mod_user_id` (`last_mod_user_id`),
  KEY `hub_id` (`hub_id`),
  KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`),
  KEY `endorsed_user_status` (`endorsed_user`,`status`),
  KEY `base_user_id` (`base_user_id`),
  KEY `endorsed_user` (`endorsed_user`),
  KEY `hub_integrated` (`hub_integrated`),
  KEY `dm_hub_employer` (`hub_id`,`is_dm_emp_hub_sync`,`endorsed_user`),
  KEY `cv_mod_created_date` (`created_date`,`is_eb_migrated`),
  KEY `job_level` (`job_level`),
  KEY `function_id` (`function_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=555665 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `base_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_eb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `eb_reff_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_uniq_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `joblevel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endorsed_user_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verification_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pass_recovery_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'verified, activated, deactivated, approved',
  `ip_addresses` text,
  `flag_eb` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 - NOT EB, 1 - EB User',
  `flag_ed_manual` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 - NOT READ, 1 - READ. Its for verifying whether the user/DM is aware of Endorsed client manual.',
  `ip_verify` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `hubspot_flag` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1=active, 2=deactive',
  `organisation_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'xero organisation id for ed manager users',
  `last_mod_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mod_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rs_company_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rs_base_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firsttime_get_started` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_cb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `zendesk_user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_sync_zendesk` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0:not sync;1:synced;2:error',
  `zendesk_sync_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag_company` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1:CB;2:EB;3:TR',
  `merge_account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interact_people_uid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interact_people_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_sync_to_interact` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0:not synced;1:synced;2:xml-error',
  `sync_interact_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_current_team` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `parsed_org_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `company_user_id` (`company_user_id`),
  KEY `org` (`organisation_id`),
  KEY `flag_company` (`flag_company`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`,`company_user_id`),
  KEY `zendesk_user_id` (`zendesk_user_id`,`is_sync_zendesk`),
  KEY `zendesk_sync_date` (`zendesk_sync_date`),
  KEY `mod_date` (`mod_date`),
  KEY `sync_to_interact` (`is_sync_to_interact`,`interact_people_uid`,`status`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `sync_interact_date` (`sync_interact_date`,`mod_date`),
  KEY `status` (`account_number`,`status`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `username` (`status`,`username`(4)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `rs_comp_user` (`rs_company_user_id`,`company_id`,`is_eb_migrated`),
  KEY `getOrganisation` (`company_id`,`company_user_id`),
  KEY `username_2` (`username`),
  KEY `eb_reff_id` (`eb_reff_id`),
  KEY `get_index_comp` (`company_user_id`,`is_eb_migrated`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=557225 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `company_team_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_mod_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mod_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `is_cb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `merge_account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_eb_migrated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `teamID` (`team_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `end_date` (`end_date`),
  KEY `getTeam` (`base_company_id`,`user_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=586851 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: please edit your question to include the EXPLAIN info in the question formatted as text. Also include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for the tables referenced. Welcome to SO

Comment: `AND (ctu.status = 2)` converts `LEFT JOIN company_team_users AS ctu` to `INNER JOIN`. Replace.

Comment: Aggregating with LEFT JOINs is a little unusual, and usually unnecessary; by definition, and row not appearing in a JOINED result has a count of 0. Also, don't quote integer data types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, move company_team_users next to the base table and use JOIN(this will short list the result based on the filter) instead of LEFT JOIN to shorten the result of the first two tables. Then remove other column filter in where clause and include it in your join.

```
SELECT 
    cs.delivery_consultant_id AS user_id, 
    interview.id AS interview_id,
    date(interview.interview_date) AS interview_date, 
    date(interview.mod_date) AS interview_mod_date,
    count(interview.id) AS kpi_item_count,
    cu.division_id,
    bu.organisation_id,
    ctu.team_id
 FROM es_shortlist AS cs
 JOIN company_team_users AS ctu ON ctu.user_id = cs.delivery_consultant_id AND ISNULL(ctu.end_date) AND ctu.status = 2
 LEFT JOIN tms_vacancies AS vac ON cs.vacancy_id = vac.id
 LEFT JOIN es_applications AS app ON app.vacancy_id = vac.id AND app.candidate_id = cs.candidate_id
 LEFT JOIN tms_interviews AS interview ON app.id = interview.application_id
 LEFT JOIN company_users AS cu ON cu.id = cs.delivery_consultant_id
 LEFT JOIN base_users AS bu ON bu.company_user_id = cs.delivery_consultant_id AND bu.company_id = cu.base_company_id
WHERE cs.delivery_consultant_id ='53521'
GROUP BY cs.delivery_consultant_id, ctu.team_id
```

Additional Note

Add index to those table columns that are commonly used in joins and where clause;

Ex:

```
es_shortlist (delivery_consultant_id)
company_team_users (user_id, end_date, status)
es_applications (vacancy_id, candidate_id)
tms_interviews (application_id)
base_users (company_user_id, company_id)
```

Comment: A slight improvement would be to add this covering index to `ctu`: `INDEX(status, end_date, user_id, team_id)`